# Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided

Tags: three.js, ionic3, webgl

I'm using ionic 3 framework to build an Android and Electron Application.

Now I've to add Three.js (the version in use is the r110) in the app and I have no experience in WebGL nor three.js.

When I run the application with Electron all seems fine, but when I run the app in an android emulator with Android API 28 this error happens "Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided."

I think the problem is that the version of chrome used by Android is "Chrome/69.0.3497.100", while in Electron is "Chrome/76.0.3809.146".

This is the part of code that use the texImage2D function

```
 private loadCollada() {
    const loader = new ColladaLoader();
    loader.load('assets/edo/model/model.dae', (collada) => {
      this.dae = collada.scene;
      this.dae.scale.x = this.dae.scale.y = this.dae.scale.z = 1;
      this.dae.updateMatrix();
      this.scene.add(this.dae);
    });
  }
```

I found in three.js library that the error is logged in three.module.js

```
    function texImage2D() {

        try {

            gl.texImage2D.apply( gl, arguments );

        } catch ( error ) {

            console.error( 'THREE.WebGLState:', error );

        }

    }
```

I don't know if it might be useful but I have also this message in my console printed so many times.

```
[.WebGL-0xcba04400]RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering. [file:///android_asset/www/index.html]
```

There is a workaround or a way to fix this problem?

Comment: The first thing I'd do is put a breakpoint on that `console.error` and check what the arguments are. If I knew what all the arguments are and their types then I might know why you get that error.

Comment: I don't know if my reply is correct, but i link you this screen with the arguments

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EOCC_8bxxEJOHe7irYsJDWBk6UE00R0z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: the function texImage2D() is called 4 times, all the times with same arguments.

Comment: Try this. At the top of your code, before you include three.js, add `window.OffscreenCanvas = function() { throw new Error(''); }`

Comment: I'm using ionic 3 framework with Angular5, I'm import three.js like ES6 module. I used this repo to start my work https://github.com/JohnnyDevNull/ng-three-template/ the only difference is that I load a collada model instead to generate a cube.

If I add the code inside ionViewDidLoad or ngOnInit the result is this:
Property 'OffscreenCanvas' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Comment: Where do you get that error? That sounds like a build time error not a runtime error? You could put it in a its own script and `import` it. Or maybe you could change it to `if (typeof OffscreenCanvas !== 'undefined') { OffscreenCanvas = undefined; }` or something to that effect. Basically you're trying to get three.js not to use OffscreeCanvas. You could also just go edit the three.js code in WebGLTextures.js not to use offscreencanvas. Effectively delete [these lines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/f7c932d6ba414ff6845f4f6b3e556799742b3e18/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLTextures.js#L27)

Comment: I get the error only when the collada model is loaded, if I create a cube like the repo does no error happens.